# Windows Server 2012 HttpWebRequest Connection Closed Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to request using httpwebrequest class. I got error closed connection altought I setted protocol tls12 in global.asax. I tought that I should set some properties in windows server cause on local this request achieved.Here code which I created.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(request);
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Close();
}
DealerPaymentServicePaymentResult dealerPaymentServicePaymentResult;

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    dealerPaymentServicePaymentResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DealerPaymentServicePaymentResult>(result);
    streamReader.Close();
}
if (dealerPaymentServicePaymentResult.ResultCode.Equals("Success"))
{
    string redirectUrl = dealerPaymentServicePaymentResult.Data;
    _httpContext.Session["OrderPaymentInfo"] = processPaymentRequest;//new processpayment value
    return Redirect(redirectUrl);

}
```

Comment: you sould be sending ContentLenght and System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Comment: ssl3 protocol doesn't work it should be tsl12